# Estou com um problema em 2 scripts...Navegação em abas

Tags: html, jquery

Bom estou tentando resolver um problema bem chato, estou tentando fazer uma page em nav de abas e ela utiliza o jquery
:"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"

Mas também estou com outra script  e ela está usando :
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

E está bugando a script, caso eu tire o jquery 1.11 minha script funciona, mas a nav em page não .

Se eu tio 3.2.1 minha script não funciona, e o nav em page funciona.

Comment: Agora foi, faz uma pergunta ai para q eu possa dar votação e se tiver como me explicar pq eu queria entender pq com essa biblioteca foi e com as outras duas não, e para ir as duas coisas a script + a nav em abas eu tive q importar as duas jquery 2.1.1 e 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algumas versões mais recentes ou mais antigas do jQuery não são compatíveis com certos plugins. Isso depende muito sobre qual versão do jQuery o plugin foi baseado (a maioria das vezes na página do plugin informa qual é versão mínima do jQuery é requerida).

Como você está usando 2 plugins diferentes e está havendo uma incompatibilidade de um ou outro com as versões do jQuery que testou, sugiro que use a versão 2.1 (inclusive é a versão usada aqui no SOpt), pois ela ainda suporta muitos métodos da versão mais recente e das anteriores.

Carregue usando a tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>
```

Sugiro também que a médio prazo procure substituir o plugin que não estava sendo compatível com a versão mais recente 3 do jQuery.

Comment: O plugin q não está indo é o do nav em aba vc teria algum doc q falasse como fazer nav em abas com a versão 3?